# Как организовать правильную последовательность массивов в списке?

Tags: php, html, массивы, wordpress, список

Приветствую! Есть интернет-магазин. Стоит задача сформировать правильный список для отправки клиенту. Для начала на странице оформления получаю необходимые значения: имя покупателя, название каждого товара, количество и цена, а также итоговая сумма. Т.к. товаров может быть больше одного: создаю под каждый массивы:

```
$total  = $order->get_total();
foreach($order->get_items() as $item)
{
  $product_name[] = $item['name'];
  $quantity[] = (int)$item['qty'];
  $price[] = wc_format_decimal( $order->get_item_total( $item ), 2 );
}
```

Далее формирую шаблон списка для отправки:

```
$args = array(
'customer_name'     => Покупатель Вася,
'total'             => total,
'product_name[]'        => $product_name,
'quantity[]'            => $quantity,
'price[]'       => $price,
);
```

Теперь завожу все данные в список для отправки:

```
foreach ($args as $key => $value) {
args_array[] = '<input type="hidden" name="'.esc_attr( $key ).'"               
value="'.esc_attr( $value ).'" />';
}
```

И в завершение хочу получить список в таком виде (чтобы товары с описанием шли один за другим в одном списке). Проблема только в том, чтобы организовать это с помощью имеющихся массивов..

```html
<input type="hidden" name="customer_name" value="Покупатель Вася">
<input type="hidden" name="total" value="2500">
<input type="hidden" name="product_name[]" value="Товар  1">
<input type="hidden" name="quantity[]" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="price[]" value="1000">
<input type="hidden" name="product_name[]" value="Товар  2">
<input type="hidden" name="quantity[]" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="price[]" value="500">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы организовал массив иначе:

```
$total  = $order->get_total();
foreach($order->get_items() as $item)
{
  $products[] = [
  'name' => $item['name'],
  'qty' => (int)$item['qty'],
  'price' => wc_format_decimal( $order->get_item_total( $item ), 2 ),
  ];
}
```

Далее объединяем с массивом пользователя:

```
$args[] = [
'customer_name'     => 'Покупатель Вася',
'total'             => $total,
'products'          => $products,
];
```

И далее выводим общий массив (хотя я бы не рекомендовал выводить пусть даже и в скрытых инпутах данные заказа, ибо их можно будет подделать, лучше в сессию писать и далее уже направлять куда нужно):

```
foreach ($args as $value) {
$args_array[] = '<input type="hidden" name="customer_name" value="'.$value['customer_name'].'" />';
$args_array[] = '<input type="hidden" name="total" value="'.$value['total'].'" />';
foreach ($value['products'] as $item) {
$args_array[] = '<input type="hidden" name="name[]" value="'.$item['name'].'" />';
// Цена и кол-во
}
}
```

Comment: почему-то не заполняется массив здесь - страница вешается   `foreach($order->get_items() as $item)
{
  $products[] = [
  'name' => $item['name'],
  'qty' => (int)$item['qty'],
  'price' => wc_format_decimal( $order->get_item_total( $item ), 2 ),
  ];
}` хотя, если по переменным раскладывать, то все норм

Comment: Сложно сказать в чем дело, нужно проверять, найти место на каком элементе массива идет зацикливание. Пробуйте, я схему массива дал.

Comment: так я любой 1 элемент оставлял в массиве - все одно. есть предположение, что на `[]` ругается, т.к. если так записать `$products = array(
     'name' => $item['name'],
     'qty' => $item['qty'],
     'price' => wc_format_decimal( $order->get_item_total( $item ), 2 )
    );` то все норм, но это не то, чего я хочу добиться. можно заполнить массив как-то без `[]` ?

Comment: решение было через `$products[] = array()` у меня php не поддерживает короткую запись